# Countries filter by user select

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**Dear programmers**, I have some objects
[like this](https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100)
and simple dropdown html selector

**How make filter by countries, depends of user select?**

Example:

user select 'Americans' -> show users from 'United States'

user select 'Canadian', 'British' -> show users from 'Canada', 'United Kingdom'

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Jiy.png)

React js
CODE:

TableTitle.js

```
const nationalities = ['american', 'australian', 'brazilian', 'british', 'canadian', 'danish', 'dutch', 'finnish',
'french', 'german', 'iranian', 'irish', 'new zealander', 'norwegian', 'spanish', 'swiss', 'turkish'];

{/*selector*/}
<Select
  mode="tags"
  size='large'
  placeholder="Nationalities"
  onChange={handleNationChange}>
      {nationalities.map((item) =>
             <Option key={item}>
                {item}
             </Option>
        )}
 </Select>
```

TableContent.js shows results:

```
const TableContent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]),
    
   useEffect(() => {
       axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100`).then(({data}) => {
       setData(data.results));
   }, []);

return <Table dataSource={data} title={() => <TableTitle/>} />
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please give more information on what code you already have. Where is the dropdown html selector? Where are the results shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to filter your data.
If you need more help with this. just comment below.

```js
let url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100";

const filterByCountry = (data, country) => {
  return data.filter((record) => record.location.country === country);
};

fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {

    //data from url loaded into variable 'data'

    //filter data according to country
    const out = filterByCountry(data.results, "Australia");
    console.log(out);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro! You help me a lot!